# How to transform an SNP matrix in Tab-delimited format into numbers using python?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, bioinformatics, biopython

I am attempting to transform the bases in the tab-delimited file into integers. The input file must be duplicated and the new copy must have a '1' for the reference base and a '2' for the most common alternate allele after that, and a '3' for for the next and so on. I'm new to python so any help is welcome, i've been attempting to use pandas because the file is so large. Here is a sample of the data:

```
dfmolecule      refpos  syn?    refbase 0.1288  1304    09BKT076207
NC_011353       68      NA            A       A    A        A
NC_011353       255     NSYN          A       A    A        A
NC_011353       493     NSYN          T       T    T        C
NC_011353       514     NSYN          C       C    C        C
NC_011353       1790    SYN           G       G    G        G
NC_011353       1798    NSYN          A       A    A        T
NC_011353       2015    SYN           C       C    C        C
NC_011353       2345    SYN           T       T    T        T
NC_011353       2655    NSYN          C       C    C        C
NC_011353       2906    NSYN          C       C    C        C
```

Output should theoretically look like this:

```
dfmolecule      refpos  syn?    refbase 0.1288  1304    09BKT076207
NC_011353       68      NA            1       1    1        1
NC_011353       255     NSYN          1       1    1        1
NC_011353       493     NSYN          1       1    1        2
NC_011353       514     NSYN          1       1    1        1
NC_011353       1790    SYN           1       1    1        1
NC_011353       1798    NSYN          1       1    1        2
NC_011353       2015    SYN           1       1    1        1
NC_011353       2345    SYN           1       1    1        1
NC_011353       2655    NSYN          1       1    1        1
NC_011353       2906    NSYN          1       1    1        1
```

This will help me visualize the SNPs better and allow me to rank the most common allele change per row. I don't know where to begin thats why I'm posting. The code I do have just converts the bases to numbers. The 'refbase' needs to always be '1' and when python reads a base that is different from the ref base across the row it substitutes the base with a '2' for the 2nd most common allele in that row. I hope thats a little more clear.

my code new code, Now just need to figure out how to rank the allele changes by frequency?:

```
import csv
import pdb
import os
import sys


if len(sys.argv) != 2:

        exit("Need arg <snp file>")

snp_file = sys.argv[1]

wtf = csv.writer(open('/users/new_snp.txt' , 'w'), delimiter='\t')




newf = list(csv.reader(open(snp_file,'rU'), delimiter='\t'))



#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Returns an array of tuples with ('A', 8)
# where the letter is the nucleotide and the number
# is the amount of times a letter is present in a row
#--------------------------------------------------------------

def refbase_count(r):

# This is a blank hash to keep count of occurances
# of the alleles

    rep = {'A':0, 'T':0, 'G':0,'C': 0}


    for i in r:

        rep[i] += 1


    # sort before returning
    import operator

    sorted_rep = sorted(rep.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

    # Want them with the most frequent first
    sorted_rep.reverse()

    return sorted_rep

 #--------------------------------------------------------------

 # print the top row outside of the loop
 print newf[0]
 wtf.writerow(newf[0])

 for row in newf[1:]:

    #rep = refbase_count(row[4:])

 for index, val in enumerate( row[4:] ):

        # If the refbase (in index 3) is equal to the
        # value at a given spot, then we give it a new value of 1
        # otherwise, it's a 2
        if row[3] == val:

            row[index+4] = 1

        else:

             row[index+4] = 2



print row
wtf.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Just to be sure, for each row, if the element matches refbase, it should be converted to 1, and refbase should also be converted to 1. It seems you seek the case when there are more than two alleles? Otherwise, everything not matching refbase could just be converted to '2'. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, but i would also like '2' to represent the most common allele other than the base. All ive been able to do is convert alleles to numbers like 'A' to 1 and 'G' to 2, but doing that doesnt help me because i cannot discern a pattern.

Comment: I would be happy right now just being able to do just '1' for ref and 2 for others.

Comment: Do you only have an even number of columns? Otherwise how do you determine the nth most common base in a row if you have e.g., {A, A, G, G} in a row?

Answer (score 0):

You should post what you've tried and what you think the output should look like. Maybe spend some time clarifying your question too.

If I understand correctly, you want to rank by the column `refbase`? To do that use

```
In [38]: rnk = df.groupby('refbase').apply(lambda x: np.size(x)).rank(ascending=False)

In [39]: rnk
Out[39]: 
refbase
A          2
C          1
G          4
T          3
dtype: float64
```

Then you can create a new column with the ranks based off that:

```
In [40]: df['refpos_rank'] = df.refbase.replace(rnk.to_dict())

In [41]: df
Out[41]: 
  dfmolecule  refpos  syn? refbase 0.1288 1304 09BKT076207 refpos_rank
0  NC_011353      68   NaN       A      A    A           A           2
1  NC_011353     255  NSYN       A      A    A           A           2
2  NC_011353     493  NSYN       T      T    T           C           3
3  NC_011353     514  NSYN       C      C    C           C           1
4  NC_011353    1790   SYN       G      G    G           G           4
5  NC_011353    1798  NSYN       A      A    A           T           2
6  NC_011353    2015   SYN       C      C    C           C           1
7  NC_011353    2345   SYN       T      T    T           T           3
8  NC_011353    2655  NSYN       C      C    C           C           1
9  NC_011353    2906  NSYN       C      C    C           C           1
```

This can be written to a tab delimited file with `df.to_csv(path, sep='\t')`

Comment: I added some more info to my question, I hope it helps clarify my problem.

Comment: If 'refpos_rank' showed the second, third, and fourth most common allele then your method would help.